# SQL to map to a new value between two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

When trying to copy the values of TableA to TableB in  SQL 2008 environment, I'm trying to conditionally map some values to a new type and value.

For example, TableA has column Letters varchar(1) and stores letters of the alphabet, and I want to move these values to TableB in column Numbers int.

```
INSERT INTO TableB( SomeColumn1, Numbers, SomeColumn2 )
SELECT SomeColumn1, 
       LetterToNumber = 
       CASE Letters
              WHEN 'A' THEN 1
              ...
              WHEN 'Z' THEN 26
       END,
       SomeColumn2
FROM TableA
```

Is this the right way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TableB( SomeColumn1, Numbers, SomeColumn2 )
SELECT SomeColumn1, 
       ASCII(UPPER(Letters)) - 64, --Uppercase A is 65 decimal, 41 hex
       SomeColumn2
FROM TableA
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's happening on that line.

Comment: gbn's correction to use UPPER instead of UCASE is correct... pardon the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Either that or use a char to ascii value conversion function...

```
Select SomeColumn1, select ascii(Letters) - 64, SomeColumn2
```

That presumes that your letters are all caps.  You can also do

```
Select SomeColumn1, select ascii(ucase(Letters)) - 64, SomeColumn2
```

That will convert lower case values to upper case before generating the integer...